# How to list all the files from a bucket in Google Cloud Storage using PHP?

Tags: php, list, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

Is there a way to list all the files from a bucket in Google Storage using php ? I was able to **upload** and **download** files by I can't find a way to list all these files ?

in the documentation there are examples of listing using java or python...but not PHP.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

So any ideas ?

Thank You!

**EDIT** I found a solution . Can anyone confirm that this is the right way ?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using PHP on App Engine (and, if you are, can you add the appropriate tag as well) or if you're trying to use it from some other hosting system?

Comment: I'm using  Google APIs Client Library for PHP .

Comment: @Prisoner can you give me an answer for this?thanks

Comment: It seems that not *all* PHP filesystem functions are supported. A full list exists in the link you provided (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#php_filesystem_functions_support_on_google_cloud_storage). I don't see scandir there and my guess is that it is not supported but readdir is supported.

Comment: @ozarov I saw that readdir is implemented.but i don't know how to use it.But I found a way to list the files from a bucket using this App Engine.See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer. I did not test it enough . It is strange we cannot find this on documentation for php.

```
            $storage = new Google_Service_Storage($this->gcsClient);
            $listObjects = $storage->objects->listObjects($this->bucket, array());
            $items = $listObjects->getItems();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
               print_r($item["name"]);
            }
```

Can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to list the files from a bucket?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, as per the client login (`$this->gcsClient`), does it need authorization and tokens as the other Google API Client libraries?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$projectId = 'my-project';

$config = [
'projectId' => $projectId,
];

$storage = new StorageClient($config);

$bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket-media-files');

foreach ($bucket->objects() as $object) {
  echo '<pre>';
  printf('Object: %s' . PHP_EOL, $object->name());
}
```

References: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects?hl=pt-br#code-samples
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/storage/src/list_objects.php